# css input text name value color

Tags: html, css

I want to colorize one input field in my form depending on the value 0 or 1, is it possible ?

My field looks like this:

```css
input[value="1"] {
  background-color: green;
}

input[value="0"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="5" id="status" name="status" value="1" />
```

But if I have another field with value 1 or 0, the other filed will be green or red too.
Is there another way to write more precise, that I only want the field with id=status or name=status to be colorised?

E.g. `input[type="text"]` & `input[name="status"]` & `input[value="1"]` ???

Comment: Have you tried `input[type="text"][name="status"][value="1"]`?

Comment: #status[value="1"] is correct, too.

Comment: @H.Jabi your version works,tnx